# Screenshot preview freezes a game for a few seconds

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I have a screenshot preview at the end of the level, but when I show it my game freezes for a bit(low fps for a few seconds). This is code I use to load screenshot and crop it(for a little preview sample). Please, help me to solve this lag issue

```
private IEnumerator ShowScreeshotPreview()
{
    yield return 0;

    screenshotTexture = new Texture2D(2, 2);
    byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(destination);
    yield return 0;

    screenshotTexture.LoadImage(fileData);
    yield return 0;

    Rect croppedSpriteRect = new Rect();
    croppedSpriteRect.height = screenshotTexture.height;
    croppedSpriteRect.width = screenshotTexture.height;
    croppedSpriteRect.y = 0;
    croppedSpriteRect.x = 0;

    croppedTexture = new Texture2D((int)croppedSpriteRect.width, (int)croppedSpriteRect.height);
    yield return 0;

    croppedTexture.SetPixels(screenshotTexture.GetPixels((int)croppedSpriteRect.x, (int)croppedSpriteRect.y, (int)croppedSpriteRect.width, (int)croppedSpriteRect.height));
    yield return 0;

    croppedTexture.Apply(); // Memory leak occurs here
    yield return 0;

    screenshotPrview.mainTexture = croppedTexture;
    yield return 0;

    ScreenshotPreviewAnimator.SetBool("visible", true);
    screenshotLoaded = true;
}
```

Comment: `File.ReadAllBytes(destination);` I/O calls are expensive, however small the file may be. Calling `Apply()` after modyfing texture data is necessary and cannot be avoided, and this costs you a few microseconds. Can the screenshots of the levels be taken in advance? Then you could just preload them advance and add them as a native `Texture2D` in the game. Remember, the fps number is probably averaged / smoothed out, so you will want to benchmark only the execution time of the script. Btw, why do you constantly `yield return 0;`? If it's not a coroutine, don't make it one.

Comment: I think you have a situation like in [This question](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/441262/why-does-coroutine-yield-return-0-sometimes-take-a.html) They tell not to call coroutines in Awake() function because system is not ready or something. Call it from Start()

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt without yields game freezes for a second. IEnumerable because of corouting.